# Getting one record from firebase with AngularFire on json attribute value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Super simple one I am sure, but I'm new to Firebase it's stumping me.  I have a JSON tree as follows in Firebase:

```
{
  "games" : {
    "-LKZxsIcVe3Uixrdxdau" : {
      "id" : "thing1",
      "name" : "This is a thing"
    },
    "-LKZxt57WpCd8ARMr1Cy" : {
      "id" : "thing2",
      "name" : "This is another thing"
    },
    "-LKZxtm8udMhEyZ3tHd5" : {
      "id" : "thing3",
      "name" : "And yet another thing"
    }
  }
}
```

I know that I can get an object by firebase ID with:

```
this.theThing = this.db.object('/games/-LKZxtm8udMhEyZ3tHd5').valueChanges();
```

How do I get a single object on `id` though please?

I've seen [how to query lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md) using `equalTo`.  Is that the way to do it?  If so, how do I return a single object and assign it to my `this.theThing` variable as above so that it also gets updated in realtime etc?

Further, is it efficient to query in this way, or should I actually be querying by Firebase ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to query with the `list` method.

```
this.theThing = this.db.list('/games', ref => ref
  .orderByChild('id')
  .equalTo('thing3')
  .limitToFirst(1)
)
.valueChanges();
```

This won't set your variable as the object `-LKZxtm8udMhEyZ3tHd5` instead it will set `this.theThing` as an `Observable`. What you might want to do is pipe the result into an RxJs Promise to get the desired result like;

```
this.db.list('/games', ref => ref
  .orderByChild('id')
  .equalTo(someId)
  .limitToFirst(1)
)
.valueChanges()
.map(first())
.toPromise()
.then(snapshots => {
  this.theThing = snapshots[0];
});
```

This should set `this.theThing` as the desired object `-LKZxtm8udMhEyZ3tHd5`. You'll be able to reference `this.theThing.id` which will have `thing3` as the value.